# How prolog work as intellegent language?

Tags: machine-learning, prolog, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have written set of rules in prolog, if rule matches particular action occurs. 
something like:

```
rule_second_question(X, Y, X, W):-
    (
        LINK_BASE == 'G',
        is_verb_form(X),
        aggregate_all(X, linkage(W, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, 'RS'), Y),
        writeln(Y),
        Count == 1,
        SUBJECT = X,
        nb_linkval(rule, 'twol')
    )
```

I could write similar rules in python, c++ also with `if` , `else`.

My program is about linguistic. I don't understand how prolog can make difference compare to other programming language.

Any help of example would be much appreciable.

Comment: Automatic backtracking makes it extremely easy to code up a depth-first search; which is very nice when you're doing tree construction naively. Of course, you can do it in any other language too, with a bit more effort. While you *can* eat steak with a spoon, there's something to be said for forks and knives.

Comment: You might want to compare programming paradigms rather than programming languages. A good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog power derives from *logical variables*, coupled with an embedded *search algorithm*, and expressive and uniform data structuring facilities.

It implements a *relational* data model, but on a more structured values domain than SQL.
In a sense, I think of it as the antesignan 'No SQL' language.

So we can code - with care - relations among complex data structures, like those that in early NLP research were deemed required.

Some easy to implement syntax sugar (so called DGC - Definite Clause Grammars), then let you write *executable* ASTs. If you think the language is (more or less) as old as C, you can appreciate its charme.

Then, NLP research was attracted by a more immediately productive paradigm: statistical parsing. Prolog, which is not oriented to arithmetic, loose its fashion.

See project [Attempto](http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/site/description/) for a valuable resource implemented in Prolog.

Also, my preferred book about Prolog, by Pereira-Shieber, is [freely available](http://www.mtome.com/Publications/PNLA/prolog-digital.pdf). It introduces Prolog by means of NLP.

Comment: "antesignan" is this a cromulent expression?

Comment: @false: oops, italics... antesignano means precursor, but it dosn't appear to be translatable. sorry